# Why SingularAttribute is not Serializable?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I want to pass a metamodel attribute of a JPA entity as a parameter to the remote interface of a session bean. As you know, type of this object is `javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute`. I was using Hibernate previously and there was no problem, but now with EclipseLink, metamodel attributes is not `Serializable`. It seems that EclipseLink populate attributes with not serializable objects. Why?

I am using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and my project dependencies are as below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and the exception stack trace is:

```
WARNING: IOP00100006: Class org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager is not Serializable
org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: WARNING: IOP00100006: Class org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager is not Serializable  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 6 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy158.notSerializable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.Utility.throwNotSerializableForCorba(Utility.java:968)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:781)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:846)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:245)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:614)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:837)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:962)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:706)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:527)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:775)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:846)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:245)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:614)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:837)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:962)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:706)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:527)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:775)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:846)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:245)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:614)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:837)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:962)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:521)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.TCUtility.marshalIn(TCUtility.java:157)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.AnyImpl.write_value(AnyImpl.java:627)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_any(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:627)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_any(CDROutputObject.java:489)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAny(Util.java:366)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.write_Array(ValueHandlerImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:233)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeArray(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:768)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:949)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:521)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.copyobject.ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.copy(ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.copyobject.ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.copy(ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.copyobject.FallbackObjectCopierImpl.copy(FallbackObjectCopierImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.copyobject.FallbackObjectCopierImpl.copy(FallbackObjectCopierImpl.java:59)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.copyObject(Util.java:771)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.copyObjects(Util.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.copyArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:439)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:227)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at ejb.test.__TestSBRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.test(ejb/test/__TestSBRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at ejb.test._TestSBRemote_Wrapper.test(ejb/test/_TestSBRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at web.test.TestMB.getValue(TestMB.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/test.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /test.xhtml @11,49 value="#{testMB.value}": javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA BAD_PARAM 1398079494 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: WARNING: IOP00100006: Class org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager is not Serializable
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA BAD_PARAM 1398079494 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: WARNING: IOP00100006: Class org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager is not Serializable
    at ejb.test._TestSBRemote_Wrapper.test(ejb/test/_TestSBRemote_Wrapper.java)
    at web.test.TestMB.getValue(TestMB.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA BAD_PARAM 1398079494 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    java.io.NotSerializableException: WARNING: IOP00100006: Class org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager is not Serializable
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:301)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.wrapException(Util.java:696)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:259)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at ejb.test.__TestSBRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.test(ejb/test/__TestSBRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: WARNING: IOP00100006: Class org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager is not Serializable
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:293)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.BAD_PARAM: WARNING: IOP00100006: Class org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager is not Serializable  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 6 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at $Proxy158.notSerializable(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.Utility.throwNotSerializableForCorba(Utility.java:968)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:781)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:846)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:245)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:614)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:837)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:962)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:706)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:527)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:775)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:846)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:245)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:614)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:837)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:962)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:706)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:527)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:775)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:846)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:245)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:614)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:837)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:962)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:521)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.TCUtility.marshalIn(TCUtility.java:157)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.AnyImpl.write_value(AnyImpl.java:627)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_any(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:627)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_any(CDROutputObject.java:489)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAny(Util.java:366)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.write_Array(ValueHandlerImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:233)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:216)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:852)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeArray(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:768)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:949)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:976)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:521)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.copyobject.ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.copy(ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.copyobject.ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.copy(ORBStreamObjectCopierImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.copyobject.FallbackObjectCopierImpl.copy(FallbackObjectCopierImpl.java:69)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.copyobject.FallbackObjectCopierImpl.copy(FallbackObjectCopierImpl.java:59)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.copyObject(Util.java:771)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.copyObjects(Util.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.copyArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:439)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:227)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Eclipselink's SingularAttribute implementation, SingularAttributeImpl extends AttributeImpl which implements Serialiable, so it should be serializable itself.  I doubt there are nightly tests for it though, so if you are encountering a problem, you might want to file a bug.  What version of EclipseLink are you using?

Comment: @Chris: I added more details to my question.

Comment: Try the the latest Eclipselink version.  The fetchGroupManager class not being serializable was fixed, but it might only be in 2.5 EclipseLink builds.