# How to write SUBSTR function in GROUP BY clause using JPA / EclipseLink Criteria api

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, eclipselink

I have to group various operations stored based on the year in which the operation has performed and get the count of each of the operations performed. I am using `eclipselink 2.4.2`. Below is the snippet of what I have tried

BuildOperation.java

```
@Table(name = "BUILD_OPERATION")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@MappedSuperclass
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@javax.persistence.Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "BUILD_OPERATION_SEQ", sequenceName = "BUILD_OPERATION_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
public class BuildOperation implements Entity, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BUILD_OPERATION_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "BUILD_OPERATION_ID", nullable = false)
    public BigDecimal buildOperationId;
    @Column(name = "BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
    public Integer buildOpTypeId;
    @Column(name = "STATUS_ID")
    public BigDecimal statusId;
    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON", nullable = false)
    public Timestamp createdOn;
}
```

Query.java

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> q = cb.createTupleQuery();

Root<BuildOperation> bo = q.from(BuildOperation.class);

final Expression<String> year = cb.substring(cb.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, bo.get("createdOn"), cb.literal("'YYYY-MM-DD'")), cb.literal(2), cb.literal(4));

q.multiselect(bo.get("buildOpTypeId"), year , cb.count(bo.get("buildOpTypeId").as(Number.class)));
q.groupBy(bo.get("buildOpTypeId"), year);

TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(q);
return query.getResultList();
```

The above code is throwing exception: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

From the eclipselink trace the equivalent query in the trace is

```
 SELECT BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID, SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(CREATED_ON, ?), ?, ?), COUNT(BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID) FROM BUILD_OPERATION GROUP BY BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID, SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(CREATED_ON, ?), ?, ?)
```

with the binding `['YYYY-MM-DD', 2, 4, 'YYYY-MM-DD', 2, 4]`. If I execute this from the sqldeveloper it works. Could you anyone throw some light on what should I do to make this work from the criteria api?

A similar question is asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433648/how-to-do-group-by-substring-in-eclipselink)

Comment: ORA-00979 means that you miss some fields in your predicates. Can you print the text of the query before you send it to the database?

Comment: If it works in SQLDeveloper it should work when issued through JPA unless there is a driver issue.  What happens if you use a Native SQL statement through JPA?

Comment: @stee1rat I have mentioned the text of the query towards the end of the post with the bind variable.

Comment: @Chris I tried the below native query implementation and it works. `Query query = em
                .createNativeQuery("SELECT BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID, SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(CREATED_ON, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2, 4), COUNT(BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID) FROM BUILD_OPERATION GROUP BY BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID, SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(CREATED_ON, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2, 4)");

        List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();`

Comment: The SQL TEXT for the native query in trrace is same as one that is printed when I use the criteria api with the exception that the bind variable are already substitued. The SQL text: `SELECT BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID, SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(CREATED_ON, YYYY-MM-DD), 2, 4), COUNT(BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID) FROM BUILD_OPERATION GROUP BY BUILD_OP_TYPE_ID, SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(CREATED_ON, YYYY-MM-DD), 2, 4)`

Comment: Try turning off parameter binding for the query then: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Query_Hints#Bind_Parameters

Comment: @Chris Now I get EJBException `error marshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.io.NotSerializableException: org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager`.

Comment: Try showing the stack trace

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.FetchGroupManager
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
`

Comment: `at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
 at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1133)`

Comment: `at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
 at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)`

Comment: @Chris see above the stack trace.

Comment: This has nothing to do with executing your query, and doesn't show what you are serializing.  Try EclipseLink 2.5 or later if you are trying Serialize metamodel attributes as outlined in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13631873/why-singularattribute-is-not-serializable